# Anaconda navigator and Spyder won't launch

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I've tried:

```
conda update --all
```

and this is what happened:

[image]

Any advice?

Comment: I can't open Anaconda Navigator either, but spyder runs fine.  i run spyder from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

You can reinstall with the latest version of anaconda. I had similar issues (don't try to update the night before an interview), and decided to reinstall instead of troubleshooting it. No issues after the reinstall.

Comment: how do you reinstall the latest version? I already have the latest version of Anaconda-Navigator, and if I try to install again it won't let me.

Comment: I downloaded the installer and ran it. https://www.anaconda.com/download/

Comment: didn't you have to install python again?

Comment: It's all in the installer file, so it was very easy.  If you have a lot of add on packages installed it would be more work.